# Undefined time to download ZIP file [ PHP ]

Tags: php

I want to donwload ZIP. My code works well but there is writen "Undefined time". I try with a smaller file and it works. The current file that i want to download is 3.76 MB, it's not a lot.

[Window with undefined time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWFXN.png)

[My folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmrOd.png)

**Code**

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=boss.zip');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( "visite1.zip" ) );
        readfile( "visite1.zip" );
?>
```

Comment: So, it *works*, as in the file downloads just fine, only the time estimate is off/wrong/non-existent…?

Comment: yes that's it, if you want i put screen to show you